# How I can pass parameter from one js file to another js file? Is it possible?

Tags: javascript, spring, reactjs

I write an application using spring and react.js. I have list of projects and nested list of tasks. When I pick a task from the list I need to redirect user to new page with task description. In order to do that I need to know taskId to send request to server. But I don't know how I can get the taskId in new page.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Look into WebRTC and single page applications (Vue.js can give you everything in a single page but with unique URL's, so the user thinks hes going to a new page even if it is technically the same page)

Comment: You can use Local Storage or Session Storage for save variables.

Comment: If you are using react-router for routing you can pass it in as a variable inside the url then access it via props inside the component that needs it.